# Is it possible to access a method without creating an instance?

Tags: ruby

I have a class within a module and it has methods:

```
module D
  class Dog
    @name = 'pluto'
    def setName( n )
      @name = n
    end
    def getName ()
      return @name
    end
  end
end
```

Can I access `getName` without creating an instance of `Dog` like the static method in C++? Something like:

```
D::Dog.getName ()
```

instead of:

```
d = D::Dog.new
d.getName()
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Don't write irrelevant things. How is `print "Hello world"` related to your question?

Comment: `D` is not a class. You can't create an instance of it.

Comment: I don't believe your example is a very good demonstration of good use of a static/class method. Why would you want the "name" property on a "Dog" class to be static? That seems like it would be much, much better as an instance method.

Comment: what is so bad about this question ? that it deserves a -3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for what is known as a class method in Ruby:

```
module SomeModule
  class SomeClass
    @class_variable = "some_string" # An instance variable on a class

    def self.some_class_method
      @class_variable # Return can be omitted in Ruby
    end

    # This is how setter methods are usually written in Ruby
    def self.some_class_method= new_value
      @class_variable = new_value
    end
  end
end

SomeModule::SomeClass.some_class_method
#=> "some_string"
```

Comment: got it : http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: @purpletech The example in this answer doesn't *print* "some_string", it just returns it. If you want the value to  be printed out, prefix the last line with `puts`. (E.g. `puts SomeModule::SomeClass.some_class_method` instead of just `SomeModule::SomeClass.some_class_method`.)